# The gap between two double-spaced footnotes is too large. How can I fix

Tags: spacing, footnotes, line-spacing

I have to have footnotes double-spaced, but if I use `\begin{doublespace}` and `\end{doublespace}` within footnotes, then the gap between two footnotes becomes too wide. Could anybody fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\footnote{\begin{doublespace}#1\end{doublespace}}}
\begin{document}
abcde\note{This is the first footnote.}
ABEDE\note{This is the second footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using a separate `\note` command to introduce the footnotes, it's better to use the `footmisc` package which has a hook for formatting the footnotes. Then if you ever need to change the footnotes to single spacing you don't need to change all your `\footnote` commands.  It's not clear from your question what kind of spacing you want between two footnotes. In the example below I've make the space a single blank line by setting the length of `\footnotesep`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{setspace} % load setspace before footmisc
\usepackage{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip} %use 1.67\baselineskip for a double space
\makeatother
\newcommand\lipsum{This is some text that will take up some space so that we can
      test if the  doublespacing is working correctly.}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\doublespacing}
\begin{document}
abcde\footnote{\lipsum}
ABEDE\footnote{This is the second footnote.}
foobar\footnote{Another footnote.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 6):

When you use `\begin{doublespace}....` some extra vertical space is included. (same as `\begin{center}` where as `\centering` does not).

Solution: Use `\doublespacing`. The MWE is

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\footnote{\doublespacing #1}} %% <-- note \doublespacing here.
\begin{document}
abcde\note{This is the first footnote.}
ABEDE\note{This is the second footnote.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to note that this enforces single spacing between footnotes even if the document itself has double spacing.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to have the same distance between footnotes as I have between lines inside the footnotes. You can do this by creating your own footnote separator length (`\myfootnotesep`) which you define as the distance between two lines (`\baselineskip`) minus the default footnote separator (`\footnotesep`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
\usepackage{footmisc}
    \renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\doublespacing} % set spacing in footnotes
    \newlength{\myfootnotesep}
    \setlength{\myfootnotesep}{\baselineskip}
    \addtolength{\myfootnotesep}{-\footnotesep}
    \setlength{\footnotesep}{\myfootnotesep} % set spacing between footnotes

\begin{document}
Yadda yadda yadda.\footnote{Agreed joy vanity regret met may ladies oppose who.
Mile fail as left as hard eyes.
Meet made call in mean four year it to.}
Yadda yadda yadda.\footnote{Agreed joy vanity regret met may ladies oppose who.
Mile fail as left as hard eyes.
Meet made call in mean four year it to.}
\end{document}
```

[image]